ffmpeg объединить MP3 файлы и сделать между ними тишину или паузу
Подскажите пожалуйста как объединить несколько MP3 файлов в один файл. целый вечер ломаю голову не могу понять Как. мне нужно объединить такие файлы с паузой или тишиной и вывести их в один файл через ffmpeg windows bat or cmd
file1.mp3|silence 3s|file2.mp3|silence 5s|file2.mp3|silence 5s|file2.mp3|silence 5s

file2 несколько раз
просто объедение два файла получается но это не то что нужно
ffmpeg.exe -i "concat:file1.mp3|file1.mp3" -acodec copy "1.mp3"

пробовал как-то вот так в разных вариациях что предлагал gemeni
ffmpeg.exe  -i "concat:file1.mp3|file2.mp3" -f lavfi -t 3 -i anullsrc=r=44100:c=2 -filter_complex "[0:a]concat[a1];[a1]anullsrc[a2];[a2]concat=n=2:a=0:v=0[out1]; file2.mp3 -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc=r=44100:c=2 [a3];[a3]concat[a4];[a4]file2.mp3 concat=n=2:a=0:v=0[out2]; [out1][out2]concat=n=2:a=0:v=0" -acodec copy "join\1.mp3"

ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex '[0:a][1:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[v]' -map '[v]' -acodec libmp3lame -aq 4 1.mp3

в сети нашёл трёхсекундный MP3 файл полной тишины но при объединении его почему-то полностью игнорирует. в проигрывателе показывается время с этим файлом но практически выходной воспроизводится без тишины
перепробовал практически всё что смог найти в Интернете и всё что мне подсказывали GPT и gemini

получилось сделать только двумя запросами
ffmpeg -i "{-Variable.bd_mp3-}" -i "{-Variable.bd_mp3_de-}" -i "{-Variable.bd_mp3_de-}" -i "{-Variable.bd_mp3_de-}" -filter_complex "[0:a]adelay=1000[a1];[1:a]adelay=1000[a2];[2:a]adelay=5000[a3];[3:a]adelay=5000[a4];[a1][a2][a3][a4]concat=n=4:v=0:a=1[aout]" -map "[aout]" "{-Project.Directory-}join\id_{-Variable.id-}_tmp.mp3"

ffmpeg-i "{-Project.Directory-}join\id_{-Variable.id-}_tmp.mp3" -filter_complex "aevalsrc=0:d=5[silence];[0:a][silence]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a]" -map "[a]" "{-Project.Directory-}join\id_{-Variable.id-}.mp3"

